# Laravel 5 : link to php page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two pages `login.blade.php` and `register.blade.php`. On my `login.blade.php` i have link to `register.blade.php` like this :

```
<a href="register.php">Register a new membership</a>
```

When i click on the link to register.php it throws the following error :

`NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:`

Both login and register are in the same views folder.

My route.php file have :

```
Route::get('/register', function(){
    return view('register');
});
```

Comment: you have set routes ??

Comment: oh yeah ! Let me update my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two things need to happen:

1) Remove the .php in your  tag.  It should be as such:

```
<a href="register">Register a new membership</a>
```

2) Make sure you are catching the 'register' route properly:

```
Route::get('register', function()
{
    return view('register');
});
```

Comment: No problem.  Kindly accept my answer on the left, if it suffices :)

Comment: You could also use the URL helper function, <a href="{{ route('routeName')}}">Register a new membership</a>

Answer (score 1):

At first give a name to your route and then use it in then use it in anchar tag

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about')->name('about');
```

Now you can use it in any page to refer them. 
like in contact page

```
<html>
..
....
<a href="{{route('welcome')}}">Home</a>
<a href="{{route('about')}}">About</a>
```